# Nice description of space of modular forms

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

It is well known that the space of modular forms for $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ (i.e. level $1$) has the structure of a graded ring generated by $E_4$ and $E_6$ in degrees $4$ and $6$ respectively. Is there a similar description for modular forms of higher level?

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66819/generators-of-the-graded-ring-of-modular-forms).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you!